# How to implement Amazon's Product Advertising API for iOS?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I'm planning to use Product Advertising API on a mobile application (preferably iOS). The Product Advertising API License Agreement clearly states you cannot use the API directly from the mobile device.

Question: Is using the API on a server, then using web service calls to get the data for the device from the server the only way? If not, what do you suggest?

Comment: Please share any progress you make on this - it seems like the door is closed to iOS at all turns, but I am still hoping to find a way to break through it (legally of course). Would love to hear if you learn of any developments that open the door to iOS!

Comment: I've built a lightweight Java EE web service, which calls the Amazon API. In the web service response the backend sends the Amazon API response.


| iOS |-request->| JAVA backend |-request->| Amazon API |-reponse->| JAVA backend |-response->| iOS |

Comment: Thanks Peter. If you look at all of the links I have posted for answers below, it seems that 1)you can't use the API without permission in a mobile iOS app and 2)you can't earn commission through a mobile iOS app. Are you doing something that allows you to 1)use the API and/or 2)earn affiliate commission through iOS? I know that it can be done technically, but can it be done 'legally'?

Comment: I'm only using it to look up items in the amazon database based on their barcode.

Comment: I still don't think you can do that 'legally'. But I am playing devil's advocate here - I want to do the same thing - so please show me that I am wrong! Check this link: https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/agreement.html?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_i=assoc-api-detail-5-v2&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_83957651_1

Comment: "(e) You will not, without our express prior written approval, use any Product Advertising Content on or in connection with any site or application designed or intended for use with a mobile phone or other handheld device (which prohibition does not apply to any site that is not designed or intended for use with such devices but that may be accessible by such devices, such as a non-mobile-optimized site accessed via an internet browser on a tablet device), ...

Comment: or any television set-top box (e.g., digital video recorders, cable or satellite boxes, streaming video players, blu-ray players, or dvd players) or Internet-enabled television (e.g., GoogleTV, Sony Bravia, Panasonic Viera Cast, or Vizio Internet Apps)."

Comment: Yes, you might be right. I'm not using it on a live system at the moment, more like a test one. But this means I might have to rethink stuff. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Let me know if you are ever able to get this working legally on iOS and I will do the same. Best wishes.

Comment: anything news regarding Product Advertising API on mobile??

Comment: In line with the legality of how to use Product Advertising APIs, can you create an app that advertises Amazon products link each product with your affiliate link. Each time the user makes a purchase you receive commission. Does that break any Amazon policies?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using the Amazon Mobile Associates API: https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/earn/mobile-associates

Comment: Amazon Associates for Mobile: "You may not earn fees by linking to Amazon through an iOS or Windows app." https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/microsite/mobile

Comment: That is no longer true: 
Starting April 1, 2016, associates can earn advertising fees by driving mobile traffic to Amazon from your mobile applications.  9from your link)

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak I can't access that link because I need to have an Amazon Affiliates account. However, I can't create one, because it requires my app to be published already and it is not. Do you know a way around this? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Contact Amazon developer support

Comment: With Amazon Mobile Associates API, how can you query details for items? With the Advertising API, I can query "Best Seller" items, for example, or even "Most Popular" items. I can query by category and rating, ect. Amazon Mobile Associates API doesn't seem to have this capability, or am I missing something in the documentation?